# Pull column data from one sheet to another, only when there is an X on first sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I want to pull data from Cell 2 into another sheet when there is an X in Cell 1, but I want this to be true for the entire column, and then display it in another sheet, what is the best way to go about this? I am by no means an expert in Excel, so the simplest way is the best way. Thanks!

Ex.
Sheet 1
Cell 1 = X
Cell 2 = Trend

Sheet 2
Populate information onto Sheet 2 from data in Cell 2 only when Cell 1 = X.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a pivot table. Put your first column in filters and filter out for "X", put your second column as row labels.